# Xfce4 mysteriously starts file browser upon login

Tags: xfce, startup

I'm using Arch Linux and currently installed Xfce4, which after I log in (using LigthDM) opens an instance of the Nemo file browser. This happens regardless what I set as the default file browser (I also tried Nautilus and Thunar). This happens only with Xfce4, using Cinnamon or Gnome doesn't reproduce this behaviour.

I checked the *Application Autostart* settings from the *Session and Startup* menu, but there is no entry for Nemo or any other file browser. I also checked the contents of `/etc/xdg/autostart/` and `~/.config/autostart/`, but there aren't any file browser related entries.

Any idea where this behaviour could be originated, or any suggestions what I could try next?

Comment: Did you `grep` or `ls` the contents of `autostart`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have something recorded in your session.
Logout from XFCE (ie: logon with another WM or from console), then remove files named `xfce4-session*` and `xfwm4*` from `~/.cache/sessions/`. Then try to logon with XFCE again.

Comment: that seems to have solved it :) there was one `xfce4-session...` file which somehow contained the line `Legacy0_Command=nemo`. The newly generated file doesn't contain any `Legacy...` entries

Comment: and it is back... for some reason nemo gets an `Legacy` entry in the session-file, although session-saving is disabled...

Comment: @tschale I've never used nemo, but after some research, it seems nemo doesn't really exit when one use it out of cinnamon. Try to launch it with `nemo --no-desktop` or quit it with `nemo -q`. See [here](https://forum.xfce.org/viewtopic.php?id=9093) for instance.