# Some of my applications are always started when I login to Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, login, startup

When I login to the system I have few `Nemo` windows open.

I did it few weeks ago, and probably forgot to close at shut down.
But now Mint remember my open application and ***always open it*** after start up:

[image: start up applications]

**UPDATE:**

Of course, I checked `Settings => Startup Application`.

***It doesn't contain*** any file browsers. It contains only desired application for me.

**UPDATE_2:**

I checked solution mentioned here [Xfce4 mysteriously starts file browser upon login](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196111/xfce4-mysteriously-starts-file-browser-upon-login).

And can conclude that it doesn't work for Cinnamon environment.
`~/.cache/` doesn't contain any `sessions` folder:

[image: session folder]

***How to get rid of this start up application?***

Comment: @JID What do you exactly mean?

Comment: @JID, the init process takes care of starting services at boot time and when changing runlevels. It does not start applications when you login into a desktop manager session. nazar_art wants to know how he can prevent the desktop manager from opening a file browser while logging in.

Comment: @nazar_art, have a look at menu / preferences / startup applications, it might be listed there

Comment: @Lambert Fair enough. I misunderstood what they meant by startup, i presumed booting.

Comment: @Lambert I updated question.

Comment: @nazar_art I think it's a duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/196111/xfce4-mysteriously-starts-file-browser-upon-login

Comment: @apaul I will check this approach, later. And tell if it solves trouble. But you link is about `Xfce4`. I'm using Cinnamon

Comment: @nazar_art yes, but the stored session should be at the same place, and I think it's above all a `nemo` issue (see the comments about `--no-desktop` option)

Comment: @apaul I updated question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were very close.

Just go into `Settings => Startup Programs` and then click on the `Options` tab.

There, you will see a checkbox saying

> Automatically remember running applications when logging out

Just uncheck it.